# using xargs to grep multiple patterns

Tags: grep, xargs

I have a file that has terms I want to grep for, with each term being one line in the file. I was thinking I could do this with xargs. What I'm able to glean from examples from the man page like this

```
find ./work -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

is that xargs appends the output of the pre-pipe command to the end of its arguments. So if the find returned `report.doc`, then xargs would construct `rm report.doc`. Is this understanding correct?

So since I want the values in my file to be in the middle of the grep command, I need to specify a placeholder. In playing around, I tried `{}`, but it didn't work:

```
$> cat strings.txt | xargs grep {} subdirectory/*
grep: string1: No such file or directory
grep: string2: No such file or directory
```

Is xargs the right tool? If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, `find ./work -print0 | xargs -0 rm` will execute something like `rm ./work/a "work/b c" ...`. You can check with `echo`, `find ./work -print0 | xargs -0 echo rm` will print the command that will be executed (except white space will be escaped appropriately, though the `echo` won't show that).

To get `xargs` to put the names in the middle, you need to add `-I[string]`, where `[string]` is what you want to be replaced with the argument, in this case you'd use `-I{}`, e.g. `<strings.txt xargs -I{} grep {} directory/*`.

What you actually want to use is `grep -F -f strings.txt`:

```
-F, --fixed-strings
  Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
  newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
  POSIX.)
-f FILE, --file=FILE
  Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
  contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
  specified by POSIX.)
```

So `grep -Ff strings.txt subdirectory/*` will find all occurrences of any string in `strings.txt` as a literal, if you drop the `-F` option you can use regular expressions in the file. You could actually use `grep -F "$(<strings.txt)" directory/*` too. If you want to practice `find`, you can use the last two examples in the summary. If you want to do a recursive search instead of just the first level, you have a few options, also in the summary.

Summary:

```
# grep for each string individually.
<strings.txt xargs -I{} grep {} directory/*

# grep once for everything
grep -Ff strings.txt subdirectory/*
grep -F "$(<strings.txt)" directory/*

# Same, using file
find subdirectory -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -Ff strings.txt {} +
find subdirectory -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Ff strings.txt

# Recursively
grep -rFf strings.txt subdirectory
find subdirectory -type f -exec grep -Ff strings.txt {} +
find subdirectory -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Ff strings.txt
```

You may want to use the `-l` option to get just the name of each matching file if you don't need to see the actual line:

```
-l, --files-with-matches
  Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input
  file from which output would normally have  been  printed.   The
  scanning  will  stop  on  the  first match.  (-l is specified by
  POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 4):

`xargs` may not be the best tool  I'd suggest `fgrep` if your file-of-strings-to-match only contains strings, not regular expressions.

```
fgrep -f strings.txt subdirectory/*
```

I suggest `fgrep` as traditional Unix `grep` and `egrep` didn't have the "-f" option.  I believe that GNU `grep` and `egrep` do have the "-f" option, so if your file has regular expressions in it, you would want to use a GNU version.